# Check whether that $A \cap B \cap C$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G, \circ) $ is group and $A,B, C$ are normal subgroup of $G$.  Check whether $A \cap B \cap C$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ or not.

Honestly,  I have tried to identify how to approach the case above,  but I can't proceed too much because more than 2 definitions of normal subgroup make me wonder which way to start. One makes me wonder is:

Can we solve it at once or one by one in assocoative property?

After all, I need your help,  at least a hint to identify it. Regards.

Comment: Start with is $A\cap B$ normal? Then if it is, so is $A\cap B\cap C$

Answer (score 1):

If by "one by one" you mean that we first show that $A \cap B$ is normal, and then apply the same result to the two normal subgroups $A \cap B$ and $C$ to show that $(A \cap B) \cap C$ is normal, then yes, that would be a very reasonable way to go about this proof.